# Reporting Services 2005 - Page Breaks While Exporting To PDF

Tags: pdf, reporting-services

I have a report .rdlc
the report contains 4 lists all contained within each other (so there are 4 levels):

```
----------------------------Page 1---------------------------------------

List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                 List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
empty space
empty space
empty space
empty space
----------------------------Page 2---------------------------------------

List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
```

In report i haven’t specified any page break(**PageBreakAtEnd or PageBreakAtStart**) in any of the Lists. the problem is when exporting to PDF it puts a page break and moves the List1 Section in to next page.

but i don’t want the list to be moved to next page. it has to continue the third set of list1 items in the page 1 and when it reaches to the end of the page then it has to move the List item to Next page below is the example what I am looking for.

```
----------------------------Page 1---------------------------------------
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
----------------------------Page 2---------------------------------------
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
List1:  Fields! items1 
      List 2:  Fields! items2
            List 3: Fields! items3
                  List 4: Fields! items4
                        Contents for List 4
```

Answer (score 0):

This usually occurs because your report content is too wide for the PDF page area.

Reduce the width of the report designer surface and the controls on the surface, until everything renders as expected in PDF. You can also play around with the page size and margins via Report > Report Properties > Layout tab - I normally reduce the page margins to 1cm instead of 2.5cm, which gives you more width for your report controls.

Comment: i have tried reducing the width drastically and various page size setting. Neither seems to be working.